# How to make onload script work again after content changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page where you select between 2 pictures, when you click one of them, the content of the div changes. The new content also has 2 pictures which will load another content when clicked. I am using javascript, but the script only loads once, so when I get to the second content, it doesn't change anymore.

I got 3 files:

Main.html - content1.html - content2.html - script.js

Main.html:

```
<div id="change">
    <div id="rightside">            
        <img src="img.jpg" class="class1" id="water" alt="right choice">
    </div>
    <div id="leftside">
        <img src="img2.jpg" class="class1" id="water2" alt="left choice">
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/script.js"></script>
```

Here is the content that will be replaced in the class change:
content1.html:

```
<div id="rightside">            
  <img src="img3.jpg" class="class1" id="water3" alt="right choice">
</div>

<div id="leftside">
    <img src="img4.jpg" class="class1" id="water4" alt="left choice">
</div>
```

this is the content that i want to replace on the next click:
content2.html:

```
<div id="rightside">            
  <img src="img5.jpg" class="class1" id="water5" alt="right choice">
</div>

<div id="leftside">
    <img src="img6.jpg" class="class1" id="water6" alt="left choice">
</div>
```

This is the script that suppose to do that:

```
window.onload = function() {

    document.getElementById("water").onclick = function() 
    {
        $('#change').load('content1.html');

    };

    document.getElementById("water3").onclick = function() {
        $('#change').load('content2.html');

    };
```

If I click the image with id water, it replace with content1, then I click the image with water3, nothing happens

Comment: The problem is that  in the onload, ` document.getElementById("water3")` doesn't exist.

Comment: Use a [**delegated event**](https://www.google.com/search?q=js+delegated+event&oq=js+delegated+event&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l4.2607j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). This approach attaches an event handler to an element that will always be on the page, waits for an event to bubble up from the dynamic content, inspects the target of the event and fires the handler if it's matches selected criteria. Though it looks as if you cold just updated the `src` of the `<img>` elements instead of replacing all of the content of `#change`.

Comment: Is there a definite rule that relates the id of the clicked image to the url of the new content. If so, the whole thing is trivial.

Comment: @hungerstar its because I change way more than the images, this is just a short version of what i have.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the complete call back to bind the new element:

```
window.onload = function() {

    document.getElementById("water").onclick = function() 
    {
        $('#change').load('content1.html', function() {
             document.getElementById("water3").onclick = function() {
                $('#change').load('content2.html');

            };
        });

    };
 };
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Nice, but doesn't work, when I get the the second set of images, the content doesn't change when I click water3 (for example)

Comment: @KidsPersonalTv I loaded that in a local webserver and it worked, Are you loading it from a webserver (http)? if not you should get a CORS error

Comment: is there a way where I can send you a complete example of what i got?